# How to increase memory footprint of SQLDeveloper

Tags: sqldeveloper

I want to use SQLDeveloper with files that are fairly large. However, performance is sluggish (at best) due to a lack of memory.

Assuming that it is a Java app, how can I increase the size of memory allocated to the VM?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Adding

```
AddVMOption  -Xmx1024M 
AddVMOption  -Xms512M
```

only to  **sqldeveloper/ide/bin/ide.conf** may not work. It's also not recommended(please see comments on the top of the sqldeveloper\ide\bin\ide.conf file). In newer version of SQL developer(for sure after version 4.x) the settings in sqldeveloper/ide/bin/ide.conf  can be overridden in

**WINDOWS:**

> C:\Users\${WINDOWS_USER_NAME}\AppData\Roaming\sqldeveloper\${SQL_DEVELOPER_VERSION}\product.conf

**LINUX:**

> /home/${USER_NAME}/.sqldeveloper/${SQL_DEVELOPER_VERSION}/product.conf

**Note:** You can find path to product.conf file in SQLDeveloper->Help->About->Properties ->Propertie name "user.conf"

You need to change

```
AddVMOption  -Xmx1024M 
AddVMOption  -Xms512M
```

in configuration files above.

Answer (score 5):

Edit your `sqldeveloper/ide/bin/ide.conf` file and change the following two lines:

```
#
# If you are getting the 'Low Memory Warning' Message Dialog while running
# JDeveloper, please increase the -Xmx value below from the default 768M to
# something greater, like 1024M or 1250M.  If after increasing the value,
# JDeveloper is no longer starting up because it fails to create a virtual
# machine, then please reduce the modified -Xmx value.
#
AddVMOption  -Xmx1024M
AddVMOption  -Xms512M
```

The other answer regarding use of `-XX:MaxPermSize` in `sqldeveloper/bin/sqldeveloper.conf` is outdated and would not work in the recent versions of sqldeveloper. Using that would result in following sqldeveloper message on startup:

> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option
>   MaxPermSize=1024M; support was removed in 8.0

Answer (score 2):

[This post](http://codechief.wordpress.com/2008/07/30/configuring-oracle-sql-developer-for-large-files-fix-out-of-memory-errors/) has useful details on where to tweak the JVM settings.

Essentially, look for ~/sqldeveloper/bin/sqldeveloper.conf and in that, look for:

AddVMOption  -XX:MaxPermSize=128M